# TypeScript dictionary with a tuple as a key

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am writing a fake in Jasmine for my Angular 5 app, and would like to store a dictionary of results which the fake should return, depending on the values of the multiple parameters passed to the fake.

I thought it might be possible to define a dictionary in TypeScript, using a tuple representing the parameters to the fake as a key and the result that should be returned as the value. Something along these lines:

```
type FakeParams = [string, ListTypes, string];
type DictionaryItem = [FakeParams, string];
const paramsDictionary: DictionaryItem[] = [];

paramsDictionary['1046', ListTypes.DirectOwners, 'sanctions'] = '123';
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript complains `Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects`. It returns the result `123` no matter what value I provide as the `string` in the first parameter of the tuple.

Is there a way to do this? If not, how else can I return different values from my fake depending on matching the values of multiple parameters to my fake?

I have thought about defining a generic dictionary type, coercing the value of the key as a string using JSON.stringify() or something along those lines; but that seems to be rather smelly.

PS I have also tried:

```
paramsDictionary[['1046', ListTypes.DirectOwners, 'sanctions']] = '123';
```

but this appears to cause TypeScript even more trouble.

Comment: Just to explain the first error "Left side has no side effect" : this is cause by the fact that a comma separated list, in TS and in JS, is evaluated left to right, and returns the right-most value. Hence, if the other "parts" have no side effects, thay are indeed useless, and equivalent to keeping the rightmost part only. Eg : the expression `1,2,3` is strictly equivalent to `3`, as a comma separated expression.

Comment: Thanks @Pac0. I have resigned myself to converting the tuple to a string and using that as they key.

Comment: that's indeed a clever solution.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but not sure, and curious as well.

Comment: In JS (and I don't think TS is different on that matter) you use the syntax `identifier[expression]` as a shortcut to access the property whose **name** is `expression` of object `identifier`. *As I understand it* (corrections welcome), expression **is implicitely converted to string**, and then the result is compared to the different keys of the object, which must be strings. What about Arrays ? well, it seems to me that the internal of arrays is no different, the underlying object behind [10, 20, 30] is actually {0: 10, 1:20, 2:30} . Tested with `Object.assign({}, [10,10,30])`.

Comment: Typescript adds type checking, and tuples which are typed/position checked arrays, but can't change the fundamental thing that all properties of any object are basically strings.

Comment: @serlingpa Did my answer below solve your problem? If yes, you can click the checkmark to make it green and accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a tuple, you can write a helper Class to encapsulate the Tuple-To-String conversion (generating the key).

Then you can use the instance of `ParamsDictionary` as-is in your question above.

```
enum ListTypes {
    DirectOwners,
    IndirectOwners,
}

type FakeParams = [string, ListTypes, string];

class ParamsDictionary {
    private map = new Map<string, string>();

    private key(p: FakeParams) {
        return `${p[0]}-${p[1]}-${p[2]}`;
    } 

    public set(p: FakeParams, value: string) {
        const key = this.key(p);
        this.map.set(key, value);
    }

    public get(p: FakeParams) {
        const key = this.key(p);
        return this.map.get(key);
    }
}

const paramsDictionary = new ParamsDictionary();

// Set a couple parameters
paramsDictionary.set(['1046', ListTypes.DirectOwners, 'sanctions'], '123');
paramsDictionary.set(['1050', ListTypes.DirectOwners, 'sanctions'], '456');

// Get a couple parameters
console.log(paramsDictionary.get(['1046', ListTypes.DirectOwners, 'sanctions'])); // prints "123"
console.log(paramsDictionary.get(['1050', ListTypes.DirectOwners, 'sanctions'])); // prints "456"
```

Try it out in the TypeScript Playground: goo.gl/e3LBRG